# Dynamic, Image, and a Trigger all walk into a bar

Tags: dynamic, image

I am seeing something strange, and I am not sure if it's something I am doing poorly in Wolfram Language or an issue with the system.

This probably best described with a minimal working example.  First, I will define a function to make it easy to create a set of images.

```
images[n_, size_] := 
  images[n, size] = 
     Table[Show@RandomImage[1, {size, size}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], {n}]
```

Now I make a DynamicModule to hold my animation which is driven by the Trigger control. In this case the there will be 100 100x100 images.

```
DynamicModule[{i}, Deploy@Column[
  {Dynamic[images[100,100][[i]]],
   Trigger[Dynamic[i], {1, 100, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity],
   Dynamic[{i}]
   }
  ], Initialization :> {i = 1}
 ]
```

Now the above seems to run with no issues on my machine (11.2, Windows 7). BUT, if the image size increase to say 600

```
DynamicModule[{i}, Deploy@Column[
   {Dynamic[images[100, 600][[i]]],
    Trigger[Dynamic[i], {1, 100, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity],
    Dynamic[{i}]
   }
   ], Initialization :> {i = 1}
 ]
```

Then my animation halts almost immediately (when I just ran it now it stopped at `i=16`.

Can anyone else reproduce this behavior?

Comment: memory? I am using macOS 10.13 and MMA 11.2 and I do not have any problem..., up to a size of 1000  :((

Comment: I'd report that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are interested in a workaround:

```
DynamicModule[{i, task},
 Column[{
   Dynamic[images[100, 600][[i]]]
 , Grid[{{
     Button["\[FilledRightTriangle]", task = RunScheduledTask[i = Mod[++i, 100, 1], .1]]
   , Button["\[FilledSquare]", RemoveScheduledTask@task]
   }}]
 , Dynamic[{i}]
 }]
, Initialization :> {i = 1}]
```

Comment: Very nice.  You'll likely get the check, but I'll keep this open for other answers.

Comment: I also found that wrapping my expression in `ExpressionCell[...,Deployed-> True]` seemed to help.

Comment: @chuy good to know, you never know what can fix those fishy fe bugs. Anyway, please report this and let us know what they said.